# Erros when using Entry Variable in craft.app.feeds.getFeedItems

Tags: templating, craft3, error, feed

I'm processing some feeds using `craft.app.feeds.getFeedItems()` and it works if I pass the limit as a hard coded number like this:

```
{% set items = craft.app.feeds.getFeedItems(entry.rssURL, '5') %}
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
      <li><a href="{{ item.permalink }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

However if I change `'5'` to a field handle I get errors. where `entry.feedLimit` is a number such as 3 or 5

```
{% set items = craft.app.feeds.getFeedItems(entry.rssURL, entry.feedLimit) %}
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
      <li><a href="{{ item.permalink }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

The errors I get is:

> TypeError Argument 2 passed to craft\feeds\Feeds::getFeedItems() must
>   be of the type integer or null, object given, called in
>   /path/to/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php
>   on line 1619

This code was previously working on Craft 2, but after the update it is now broken. I've temporarily hard coded the limit in, but that's not ideal.

Comment: What type of field is `feedLimit`?

Comment: it's a select and I solved it by changing code to entry.feedLimit.value

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple, the field type is a select so I need to change

`entry.feedLimit`

to

`entry.feedLimit.value`

And then it works